# Neo4j needs more memory, but "Java cannot reserve enough space for object heap" (Windows 10)

Tags: java, neo4j

Neo4j (Community version 3.4.8) complains that "there is not enough memory to perform the current task", and advises changing a line in the config file, to increase "**dbms.memory.heap.max_size**"

If I increase that value too little, the out-of-memory problem persists.  If I increase it too much, during neo4j's start, it complains:

> "Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> Could not reserve enough space for [some number]KB object heap"

I found some answers on Stack Overflow about this issue for running Java in general... but I *don't directly interact with Java*.  I imply issue the command "neo4j console" to start Neo4j, and then Neo4j starts Java.

I am on **Windows 10**, with "**Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 181**" and "**Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 181 (64-bit)**" installed.

BTW, I am completely new to Java.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the documentation for [Neo4j memory configuration](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/memory-configuration/). With later versions you can use `neo4j-admin memrec` to provide recommendations to set based upon your current system's hardware.

In any case if possible you should upgrade, as 3.2.8 is at least two minor versions behind the latest release. At the very least, consider upgrading to the latest patch version along the 3.2.x line (currently 3.2.13) to take advantage of bug fixes and improvements.

Comment: Oops, that was a typo, sorry.  I am using version 3.4.8  (corrected).  I see that there is a 3.4.9 that just came out...

Answer (score 0):

THIS SOLVED MY PROBLEM:

1) I completely **uninstalled and reinstalled Java**. Again, the Windows 10 control panel is showing Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 181" and "Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 181 (64-bit)"

2) I upgraded Neo4j to the latest version ( **Community Edition 3.4.9** )

It's working now :)))) That is, after dealing with the issue of no longer finding Java, which is [documented and resolved here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/12057). That side issue seems to point fingers to having had 2 versions of Java, a 32-bit and a 64-bit one, and somehow it was seeing the 32-bit one. Presumably, that was the cause of the original issue.

Incidentally, the exact changes I made in the `NEO4J_HOME\conf\neo4j.conf` file are:

```
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=512m # Uncommented
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=1212m # Uncommented and increased value
```